# Loop Through Class Object in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through the object and get the value of `_dBrutto` attribute

```
object(oxPrice)#428 (6) {
  ["_roundPrices":"oxPrice":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_roundPrices":"ZmbEngine_oxPrice":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_dBrutto":protected]=>
  float(141.625)
  ["_dNetto":protected]=>
  string(7) "141.625"
  ["_dVat":protected]=>
  float(0)
  ["_blNetPriceMode":protected]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

I tried with code for loop like this:

```
foreach($oxPrice as $oxPrc){
    var_dump($oxPrc);
}
```

and

```
foreach($oxPrice as $oxPrc => $value){
    var_dump($oxPrc, $value);
}
```

but without success.

Any suggestion or idea?
Thank you.

Comment: @ThisGuy You *can*; just not non-public properties…

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: what is the output you get from var_dump?

Comment: There is no output of the foreach.

Comment: @AroshaDeSilva If I am not mistaken, see `object(oxPrice)#428`

Comment: Those are protected properties so they cannot be publicly accessed. If you have control over the class then you can build in a few `get` methods like `get_dBrutto()` or `getAllProperties()` or you can try looking into reflection.

Comment: If this is your class, add some get methods. If it's not, then whoever wrote it either will already have done so, or didn't want you to have access to them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`_dBrutto` has a protected type meaning it can only be accessed by itself or a class extending the `oxPrice` class. If you can modify this class, create a getter or make the property public (recommend the getter - public properties are ripe for abuse).

```
/**
 * @var float
 */
private $_dBrutto;

public function get_dBrutto()
{
    return $this->_dBrutto();
}
```

Then you can access it as: `$oxPrice->get_dBrutto();`

If you cannot modify this class, then there's probably a reason. You can force it but it's not recommended and I only do this for the purpose of a test where I do not want a setter or a getter method but need to test increments, ID specific values or mutations.

So we can use a `ReflectionClass`.

```
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass(oxPrice::class);
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('_dBrutto');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
echo $reflectionProperty->getValue($oxPrice); // 141.625
```

Here's an example usage with functions:

```
var_dump(getProtectedProperty('_dBrutto', $oxPrice)); // 141.625

setProtectedProperty('_dBrutto', 150.666, $oxPrice);
var_dump(getProtectedProperty('_dBrutto', $oxPrice)); // 150.666

function setProtectedProperty($property, $value, $object)
{
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
    $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty($property);
    $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
    $reflectionProperty->setValue($object, $value);
}

function getProtectedProperty($property, $object)
{
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
    $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty($property);
    $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
    $reflectionProperty->getValue($object);
}
```

Comment: I have to access the _dBrutto and multiply it by some number depending of the case. 
That's why I have a big problem.
Main problem is not to get it, because there is a function getBruttoPrice that will return _dBrutto, but I need to change it. Later that changed price will be exported in csv file...

Comment: I think you might need to update your question - this answers your current one I believe but as for changing it, given there is no setter method, you can use the same but instead of `$reflectionProperty->getValue($oxPrice)`, use `$reflectionProperty->setValue($oxPrice, <THE VALUE>);`

Comment: Hi, I tried with `$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($oxPrice));` and then `$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('_dBrutto');` but when I am doing `var_dump($reflectionProperty);` I am recieving: `object(ReflectionProperty)#942 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "_dBrutto"
  ["class"]=>
  string(7) "oxPrice"
}`

Comment: You're part way there! You are dumping the reflection property object. You need to set is as accessible and then get it or set it. `$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);` then $reflectionProperty->setValue($oxPrice, <THE VALUE>);. To check the new value, `var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue($oxPrice));`

Comment: @Dextranovich - have added some examples to the answer for getting and setting

Answer (score -2):

You can directly access value of _dBrutto without loop.
Try below.

```
var_dump(oxPrice->_dBrutto);
```

Comment: Not if it's private or protected

Comment: This solution will throw `Exception: Cannot access protected property ...`